# Problem logging on to SQL Server Manager Studio Express 2005 using Windows Authentication Mode

Tags: sql-server-express

How do I logon to SQL Server Manager Studio Express 2005 using Windows Authentication Mode?  When I try to logon I get the following error message

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

Thank You,

NH

Answer (score 0):

Check the server name. If it is your local server, try connecting to server name `.` or `(local)`, or `.\SQLEXPRESS` if the server instance is names `SQLEXPRESS`. If it is a remote server, you may have to enable some network protocols and/or enable remote connections on that server.

Comment: thank you for this information.  I tried this but got the same error message.  I believe I have a local server so I tried this method.  I am not connected to a network just to my PC.  Any other suggestions?  Thank You.  NH

Comment: Well, it may be obvious, but is SQL Server installed? You can check that in the Services (in Administrative Tools), you should see a SQL Server service and the instance name (if any).